# jqGrid IE7 hover nightmare

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jqgrid

I've wasted too much time on this and am begging, ***begging***, I tell you, the stackoverflow community for help!

I'm a new jqGrid user, and have my grid working as I want it to, but at the moment, cannot get a row to highlight in IE 7 as the mouse is hovered over it. Our shop is currently running IE7, so changing browsers/versions is not a possibility. Hover works great in Firefox, does not work in IE7.

I have googled endlessly for "jqgrid ie7 hover", "jquery ie7 hover", and any iteration of "ie7" and "hover", and "css" and all that.

I have tried so many variations of DOCTYPE declarations it ain't funny. I've tried reverse engineering the http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html demo pages until my fingers are aching. Yes, the hover works on the demo pages. No it ain't working on my own page. I have tried manually passing in the ui hover CSS classes directly with different attributes and the !important flag just to see if I get anything. Nothing.

**Now here is what does happen when I hover over a jqGrid row with IE7:** The bottom and right borders of the table cells will change color, but the background color does not. So, I know the hover highlighting is working for the cell borders, but not for the cells or row itself.

As a diagnostic aid, I slapped in a javascript alert() to bang when I hovered over the table. It works at the table level, but does not ever fire if I set it to fire if I hover over a row or cell. I used the IE Developer Toolbar DOM parser to verify I'm calling it right. I'm wondering if jqGrid takes over that functionality, though.

**Anyhow, folks, the short version is: Why can't I get row highlighting to work in IE7?**

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!

Comment: Can you post any of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. The problem was a conflict with a separate .css file. My page uses the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs) for layout control. One of the items used as part of the grid system is a "reset.css" which was conflicting with the jqGrid hover display in my app. I commented out the call to reset.css and the problem went away. Fwiw, I did not see any other adverse affects to the grid system by leaving out reset.css.